# android emulator crash while opening on mac os x with no error

Tags: android, android-emulator

i have a problem with android emulator . when i try to open android emulator in AVD manager it will try to open android emulator up but while opening it crashes . and i even don't know how to give you more information about my error  and i don't know where to find a log of my error.
things that i tried already :

1-decreasing RAM and VM RAM to 512 MB

2-using a different api

3-restarting android studio

i have no idea what should i do now . before trying in api 25 i had a emulator base on api 24 and it didn't crash but freez on android logo and after installing api 25 now both emulator crash while opening .

[image]

mac os 10.11.6

core2due 2.4

4 GIG RAM

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the android monitor in Android studio? (Bottom left) Also,  make sure you select Error in the drop-down menu.

Comment: i checked android monitor but nothing showed there . and i when i select error nothing changed .